# Downloading all maven dependencies

Tags: maven

Trying to download all maven dependencies for a complex project to speed up subsequent builds. There are some dependencies that are not outlined on `pom.xml`, such as `com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-compiler` which are triggered as part of the `generate-sources` phase (from a dependency I do include [apollo-client-maven-plugin](https://github.com/aoudiamoncef/apollo-client-maven-plugin/blob/main/pom.xml))

my original plan of using `maven dependency:go-offline` did not work because these jars are not included.

i'm currently using the work around `maven dependency:go-offline generate-sources` which ensure that those extra jars are downloaded, but now i have to wait for the actual generation of the sources...

Is there a way to just force maven to detect dependencies fully?

Alternatively, any way to have incremental `mvn --offline`, i.e. uses the jar locally without updating repository info, but do download missing ones?

Comment: if the extra jars are downloaded once, are future builds not as fast as they can be?

Comment: I also do not understand: The dependencies are downloaded once and then they are in the local repository. What would you like to speed up?

Comment: some dependencies are NOT downloaded by that. See https://github.com/aoudiamoncef/apollo-client-maven-plugin/issues/55  And after they are NOT downloaded, using `--offline` will fail the build.

Comment: @JFabianMeier see above

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen see above

Comment: Empty the .m2/repository cache.  Run all the steps you need.  The .m2/repository cache now contains all your dependencies.   Persist that between builds. A long while back I played with converting this into a local Maven file repository going in the project itself which worked reasonably well but resultet in a very big git repository.  We ended up using a Nexus docker instance mirroring Maven Central right next to the build instead.  Fast enough and kept the git repository small.

Comment: this is being run on a newly created container (think `go-offline` as a  Dockerfile step, then store the container, and use it on offline builds later). I think my problem is that apollo-client-maven-plugin have ways to download things at runtime that are not compatible with `go-offline`

Comment: Just persist .m2/repository between runs.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i'm trying to figure a solution where the image creation have access to the internet, and the execution does not. my work around is to call the execution phase `generate` during image creation, which is not desirable. mostly trying to understand how the appolo and other plugins can inject dependencies on the fly in a way that `go-offline` doesn't catch them.

Comment: go-offline tries to make a good guess about the standard plugins it knows about.  It doesn't actually run them.  Hence, this won't work for you.